# PHP Deprecated: You are retrieving the service locator from within the class ZFTool\Controller\ModuleController

Tags: zend-framework, zend-tool

I have installed zend tools using composer

```
$ composer require zendframework/zftool:dev-master
```

zftool has been installed and when I run php /vender/bin/zf.php modules list it's throwing warning

> PHP Deprecated:  You are retrieving the service locator from within the class ZFTool\Controller\ModuleController. Please be aware that ServiceLocatorAwareInterface is deprecated and will be removed in version 3.0, along with the ServiceLocatorAwareInitializer. ...

I am using Ubuntu

Comment: This error occurs after u have update your zend. Believe me i have been searching for a solution from past 2 days and thr is not even a single proper article which describes how to solve this.

Comment: I receive this error also and have not found a solution or a recommended solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few solutions:

- In your error_reporting, disable `E_USER_DEPRECATED` reporting. This
  just masks the problem.
- Pin to an earlier version of zend-mvc (e.g.,
  composer require `"zendframework/zend-mvc:~2.6.0"` will pin
  specifically to the 2.6 series, and will not install the 2.7 series).
  This, again, just masks the problem, and will potentially leave your
  application insecure if security patches are applied to a later minor
  release of zend-mvc.
- Fix your code to no longer use
  `getServiceLocator()`. This is the recommended path. The way to
  accomplish this latter point is to ensure that all dependencies for
  your controller are injected during instantiation.

This will mean:

- You need to create factories for your controllers.
- You will need to update your controllers to accept dependencies in their constructors that were previously pulled from `getServiceLocator()`.
  As an example, let's say you had something like this in your controller:

`$db = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Db\ApplicationAdapter');`

You would change your code as follows:

- Add a `$db` property to your class.
- Update your constructor to accept the database adapter, and assign it to the property.
- Change the above line to simply `$db = $this->db` (or just use the property!)
- Add a factory for your controller, if one does not currently exist.

So:

```
use Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterInterface;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;

class YourController extends AbstractActionController
{
    private $db;

    public function __construct(AdapterInterface $db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function someAction()
    {
        $results = $this->db->query(/* ... */);
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

Your factory would look something like this:

```
class YourControllerFactory
{
    public function __invoke($container)
    {
        return new YourController($this->get('Db\ApplicationAdapter'));
    }
}
```

In your application or module configuration, you would map this factory to your controller:

```
return [
    'controllers' => [
        'factories' => [
            YourController::class => YourControllerFactory::class,
        /* ... */
        ],
        /* ... */
    ],
    /* ... */
];
];
```

This may seem like a lot of steps. However, it ensures your code has no hidden dependencies, improves the testability of your code, and allows you to do cool things like substitute alternatives via configuration.

Comment: I could not get this to work until, in your second code block, I changed `$this->get('` to `$container->getServiceLocator()->get('`.